# Writing an object to the file

Tags: java, eofexception

What I am trying to do is writing a HashMap to a file. The code below correctly when run at once. However when i try to run just writing the object to the file and try to just run reading the written object to file individually it throws the following exception.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FileIo {
    String fileName;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    public FileIo(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("created");
            }
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeToFile(Object obj) {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public Object readFromFile() {
        try {
            return ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        FileIo fi = new FileIo("tex.txt");
        //Only write to the file
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add("test");
        map.put("testput", a);
        fi.writeToFile(map);
        //Only write to the file
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Only read from the file
        map = null;
        map = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) fi.readFromFile();
        System.out.println(map.toString());
    }
}
```

//Exception

```
    java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2608)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1319)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at FileIo.readFromFile(FileIo.java:49)
    at FileIo.main(FileIo.java:73)
```

The only thing happening different is instead of directly writing and instantaneously reading it. I first write the object program finishes then run the program runs to read the object.

Comment: You need to create the `FileInputStream` after the data has been written to the file. You can't create it before and assume it will show subsequently written data.

Comment: add that as an answer @AndyTurner :D

Comment: @AndyTurner the code works fine when I run it as it is. But when I slightly modify the code such that at any given time I am either writing to the file or reading from it. So in what I tried doing was first run the program to only write to the file and then re-run the program to read from it, throws the above exception. So in that case FileInputStream would always be created after the data has been written to the file.

Comment: are you commenting stuff out every time you read/write?  because your main keeps modifying the content.  try andy's solution, moving your filestream/objectstream constructors into just the read/write methods instead of creating them in the constructor.

Comment: The `exists/createNewFile` block is a complete waste of time and space. `new FileOutputStream` already creates a new file, and deletes it if it exists, or rather the OS does that when the `FileOutputStream` is constructed. You're just tripling the work required.

Comment: @JohnGardner Thank you it seems to work. But I don't understand why would it throw an exception in the previous case. Thank you for help though.

Comment: @EJP thank you for informing me!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the `FileInputStream` after the data has been written to the file.

You can't create it before and assume it will show subsequently written data.

Comment: the general problem here is that you should create your streams and read from them at the last possible instant.  so instead of creating them in the constructor, you should create them when you actually need to write/read from them.  (that way you also don't waste opening them if nobody writes or reads, like if you were to write once but read many times)